# are there any solutions or algorithms for detecting liquid in computer vision?

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, deep-learning, vision

This question just came up in my mind with curiosity.
So my question is that are there any solutions or algorithms detecting liquid such as water, coffee or something like this.
What I would like to do with this is just define whether it is liquid or not.

any ideas and comments are appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps find a machine learning forum to have a discussion about this. Or perhaps try to create such an algorithm yourself, and we can help here if you cannot get your algorithm to work.

Comment: Is the liquid flowing or static ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a paper about [Detection and Tracking of Liquids with Fully Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06266). A quick google search would have found it. And of course, it uses Deep Learning :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I am not sure if "A quick google search would have found it." and the like are helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't tell the state of matter with vision (be it computer or human).

[image]

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Comment: I think you need to explain better why it can't be done.

Comment: @PJvG: can you tell me if those silver bullions are liquid ? A picture is worth hundred words.

Comment: I can see that the melted silver that is being poured from the bucket is liquid, and this would be even more obvious if this was a video. An algorithm might be able to detect this too if it gets feeded a video. I agree that it's not clear whether the silver bullions in the mold are liquid just by looking at a picture, but this doesn't mean it can never in any case be detected what the state of matter is by using vision. You just have to approach it in a different way. A picture is worth hundred words you say, but it still leaves me confused about why you think it can't be done.

Comment: @PJvG: obviously because the surface of liquid and solid silver have exactly the same reflectance properties. Even measuring the temperature with IR wouldn't help. When the silver is at rest, a video is a still image, and I doubt that the OP was speaking of flowing liquid.